# Input in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I used a form and some JavaScript to take data from an uploaded CSV file and created an HTML table based on that data. In addition, I added an extra column for user input. My issues is that I cannot figure out a manageable way to take the user input at each input tag and replace the input tag with the text they entered.

### Code

This is the code behind the table. When I implement it, there will not be a finite number of rows though. Instead the amount of rows will be based on the data from the CSV file.

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.classList.add('table');

var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var headRow = document.createElement('tr');
var columnNames = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var th = document.createElement('th');
  th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(columnNames[i]));
  headRow.appendChild(th);
}

thead.appendChild(headRow);

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');

    if (j == 3) {
      td.classList.add("input");
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = "text";
      td.appendChild(input);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      continue;
    }
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
td { width: 25vw; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

### Table Example

[image: Table Example]

Comment: You probably have to add some kind of button to trigger the replacing, since you don't really know when the user is done typing in the input. Then make a click event that finds all input elements that have values in them, or just the input associated with the button. Then you can replace the input with its value with either innerHTML or replaceChild().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle the cells between input and text cells by doing the following.

```js
function toggleInputCells(button) {
  var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    var input = cell.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    if (input != null) {
      var text = input.value;
      cell.innerHTML = text;
    } else {
      var text = cell.innerHTML;
      cell.innerHTML = '';
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = "text";
      input.value = text;
      cell.appendChild(input);
    }
  }
}


var rows = 10;
var cols = 4;

var table = document.createElement('table');
table.classList.add('table');

var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var headRow = document.createElement('tr');
var columnNames = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var th = document.createElement('th');
  th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(columnNames[i]));
  headRow.appendChild(th);
}

thead.appendChild(headRow);

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');

    if (j == 3) {
      td.classList.add("input");
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = "text";
      input.value = 'Row #' + (i + 1); // Add a value?
      td.appendChild(input);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      continue;
    }
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
td { width: 25vw; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="button" value="Toggle Input" onClick="toggleInputCells(this)" />
```

You could also listen to when the user clicks down on the cell and convert it to an input. After they leave focus, you can convert it back into a regular text cell.

```js
function makeEditable(e) {
  var cell = e.target;
  if (cell.dataset.editing !== 'true') {
    cell.dataset.editing = true;
    var text = cell.innerHTML;
    cell.innerHTML = '';
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.addEventListener('blur', makeNonEditable);
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = text;
    cell.appendChild(input);
  }
}

function makeNonEditable(e) {
  var input = e.target;
  var text = input.value;
  var cell = input.parentElement;
  if (cell.dataset.editing === 'true') {
    cell.dataset.editing = false;
    cell.innerHTML = text;
  }
}

var rows = 10;
var cols = 4;

var table = document.createElement('table');
table.classList.add('table');

var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var headRow = document.createElement('tr');
var columnNames = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var th = document.createElement('th');
  th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(columnNames[i]));
  headRow.appendChild(th);
}

thead.appendChild(headRow);

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');

    if (j == 3) {
      td.addEventListener('mousedown', makeEditable); // Add mousedown listener.
      td.innerHTML = 'Row #' + (i + 1);               // Add a value?
      tr.appendChild(td);
      continue;
    }
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
td { width: 25vw; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the user is done entering the text when they switch to another input, you can attach a blur listener to each input.

```
<input type="text" onblur="z(this)">

z = function(input){
  var newEl = document.createElement('span');
  newEl.innerHTML = input.value;
  input.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, input);
}
```

here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nqmhpp88/